# Como usar un template string como condicion a testear en un if?

Tags: javascript

No se siquiera si la pregunta esta bien formulada. Supongamos este condicional:

```
if(!form.email.trim()) {...}
```

esta evaluando que el campo email del objeto form no venga en blanco. Ahora bien, en mi caso esta template string me generaria esta cadena de texto:

```
let cadena = `!form.${e.target.name}.trim()`;
console.log(cadena); //resultado: !form.email.trim()
```

Pero el caso es que no puedo usar esto:

> **if(cadena) {...}**   como si fuese:   **if(!form.email.trim()) {...}**

tambien intente:

> **if([cadena]) {...}**   como si fuese:   **if(!form.email.trim()) {...}**

y no funciono.

Y por ultimo intente:

> **if(`!form.${e.target.name}.trim()`) {...}**   como si fuese:   **if(!form.email.trim()) {...}**

y nada (no me imprime aqui los backtics, pero los puse).
Es posible lo que quiero hacer?

Comment: Debería funcionar sin problemas, solo un par de cosas a tener en cuenta, cadena no debería ser un string, sino directamente form.email.trim() y en el if deberías poner if(!cadena) si quieres hacer la negación. En este caso let cadena = `!form.${e.target.name}.trim()`; - sería let cadena = form.e.target.name.trim(). Y si da algún problema podrías poner e.target.name en una variable y finalmente cadena = form.variablecreada.trim(). Y luego el ! dentro del if. Comenta como te fue, si sirve lo agrego a respuesta para que le sirva a otros.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás definiendo como string esto: `!form.${e.target.name}.trim()`;

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
 let cadena = form.e.target.name.trim();
```

En ocasiones da problemas utilizar con algunos métodos estructuras así **x.y.z**, en esos casos podrías poner por ejemplo una variable auxiliar ej:

```
const auxValue = e.target.name
```

Y luego hacer algo así:

```
let cadena = form.auxValue.trim();
```

Finalmente en el `if` hacer o no la negación con `!`. Ej:

```
if(cadena){.....}
```

o

```
if(!cadena){.....}
```

Espero ayude a resolver tu inconveniente. Quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: ya probe todas estas opciones antes y no me funcionaron. para let cadena = form.e.target.name.trim(); da error e no esta definido. Y para const auxValue = e.target.name y luego let cadena = form.auxValue.trim(); da error auxValue no esta definido

Comment: Es que no hay material suficiente para poder ayudarte, quizás si subieras el código o repo capaz podríamos realizar pruebas y ver donde está el problema.